# regex.exec coming back 'null' when others are pulling back their values

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a match for a regex, but it keeps saying it's 'null'. I have declared a different variable the exact same way and it pulls back the values just fine.

- I've made sure ecommerceRegEx consoles out its value.
- I've made sure ecommercePortalAppointmentTime consoles out its value.
- I've added an await to the .exec, which worked for the other variable declaration.
- I've made sure everything is spelled correctly and all variables are being referenced correctly.

```
//RegEx I am using
var ecommerceRegEx = /((?<time>\d+:\d+) (?<modifier>[AP])M (?<timezone>[A-Z]+))/gm

//Object I am getting the DOM property for
var ecommercePortalAppointmentTime = await Selector('[class="availability-option"]').find('span').nth(0).innerText

//Match I am attempting to create
var ecommercePortalMatch = ecommerceRegEx.exec(await ecommercePortalAppointmentTime)

//Console.log I am verifying the value is returned correctly
console.log("Ecomm Match: " + ecommercePortalMatch)

//Returns 'null'
```

Expected result: An array should be created with the values per group. For example if the string is: "Your appointment is at 9:00 AM CDT", the array should be [9:00, AM, CDT]

Actual result: returns 'null'

Comment: Don't use `/g` if you're not using the regexp in a loop on the same string.

Comment: What is `Selector()` and why is it asynchronous?

Comment: I'm using an automation tool called testcafe. Selector() is a part of their tool to help find an object on the screen.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the regexp matching the input?

Comment: Do you see the expected string if you use `console.log(await ecommercePortalAppointmentTime)`?

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `ecommercePortalAppointmentTime` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @trognanders: Yes, we used regex101.com and built the expression with the string to make sure it was matching.

Comment: @Barmar, and ray hatfield: all the consoles are returning what they should, except for ecommercePortalMatch, which is returning 'null'

Comment: Try the regexp in the browser console...

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd `await` inside your `ecommerceRegEx.exec` does not make sense. You already used `await` to get that variable.

Also, your regex is not a valid JavaScript regex because JS doesn't support named capture groups. It looks like when you debugged it on regex101.com you used the PHP option. You can change that on the left menu.

Try this:

```
//RegEx I am using
var ecommerceRegEx = /((\d+:\d+) ([AP])M ([A-Z]+))/gm

//Object I am getting the DOM property for
var ecommercePortalAppointmentTime = await Selector('[class="availability-option"]').find('span').nth(0).innerText

//Match I am attempting to create
var ecommercePortalMatch = ecommerceRegEx.exec(ecommercePortalAppointmentTime)
```

Comment: When I don't have the await in there, it returns 'null'. I added the await to my other variable declaration and that's when it started pulling back its value: var staffMatch = staffRegEx.exec(await staffAppointmentTime). We're thinking it has to something to do with how TestCafe utilizes async and awaits.

Comment: You shouldn't be just randomly adding `await` and hoping stuff works. You only need `await` if something returns a promise. Add a `console.log` immediately after you `var ecommercePortalAppointmentTime....` line to verify it has a valid value already before you try to use the `ecommerceRegEx.exec`. What does that tell you?

Comment: It gives me the value of the string I am expecting.

Comment: If `ecommercePortalAppointmentTime` isn't a promise, doesn't `await` just return it normally?

Comment: Ok, so the `await` is overkill, but probably won't hurt. The problem is your regex. I've updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: Updated the RegEx and still returns 'null'.

Comment: Here's an article on groups with js: https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups

Comment: I guess regex101.com is wrong then, or I'm missing something. I'm stuck then. If you can update your question with a minimal working example that shows the problem, I might be able to try more. The JS Fiddle feature is great, you can include running code right in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `g` modifier in the regexp. This should only be used with `.exec()` when you're using the regexp in a loop to find all the matches in a single string. It causes the regexp to remember the position in the string where the match ended, so that the next call can look for a match after that.

But if you use the regexp with a different string, it will start looking in that string from the index where it found the match in the previous string. If that's after the match in this string, it won't find it.

The `g` modifier is also useful when using `.match()` to return all the matches of a regexp in an array (but then you can't get the capture groups, which is why you ), and with `.replace()` to replace all the matches.